# how to write a wrapper class using visual force pages in a pdf format

Tags: visualforce, custom-object

I want to create a Visual force page in a PDF format for a Standard object "Quote",apart from this object their are other objects fields(such as quotelineitem ,competitor,opportunity,account) which needs to called out and custom object as opportunity forecast which does not have a relationship with Quote object.Now how can i call them .For opportunity forecast how can i create a pivot table with in a visual force page ,which is created in a pdF format .Any Suggestion plz. I shall appreciate if some one helps me out with an example.

I do have few doubts: Can any one clarify on it

1. To create a Visual force page in a PDF format :We need to use html / css
2. Related objects fields are called using tags
3. How to call the custom object(Opportunity forecast) fields which are not linked to the "Quote" object
4. for this custom object (Opportunity forecast) ,how can i create a pivot table ,in vf page pdf format.

VF page :

```
<apex:page standardController="Quote" extensions="QuoteContentController"
        applyHtmlTag="false" renderAs="PDF" showheader="false">

    <head>
        <link href="{! $Resource.advancedpdfresource }" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
<head>
    <style>
        @page {
            margin: 1px 50px 225px 50px; 
            size:A4;
            Padding-top:30px;

            @top-center { 
                    content : element(header);
                 }

            @bottom-center {
                    content : element(footer);
                    height:200px;
                    padding-top:10px;
                 }
        } 
        body { font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS'; }
        .companyName { font: bold 30px; color: red; }  
        table {width:100%; border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse; border-width: 1px; border-color:#C0C0C0;border-style:solid;} 
        .header-table-data { border-width: 1px; border-color:Black;border-style:solid;background-color:#FFFFFF;
                             color:Black; font-size:14px; font-family:Verdana;
                             text-align:center;}
        .header-table-heading {border-width: 1px; border-color:Black;border-style:solid;background-color:#C0C0C0; 
                               font-weight:bold;color:Black; font-size:14px; font-family:Verdana;
                               text-align:center;}
        .header-data { border-width: 0px; border-color:Black;border-style:solid;background-color:#FFFFFF;
                       color:Black; font-size:14px; font-family:Verdana;text-align:left; padding-right: 10px;}

        .header-heading {border-width: 0px; border-color:Black;border-style:solid; 
                         font-weight:bold;color:Black; font-size:14px; font-family:Verdana;
                         text-align:left;}

    </style>

</head>

    <div class="title"> <Center > <b>RFQ Information  {!Quote.Name}</b> </Center></div>

    <b>General Inforamtion</b>
    <table  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr width="100%" border="0">


          <!--  <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><font face="Arial">Pos.</font></td>

            <td class="table header">Customer Name</td> -->

            <td class="labelCol">Customer Name</td>
            <td class="data2Col"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Name}"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="labelCol">Price</td>
            <td class="data2Col"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Totalprice}"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="labelCol">Subtotal</td>
            <td class="data2Col">{!Quote.Subtotal}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="labelCol">BillingName</td>
            <td class="data2Col">{!Quote.BillingName}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="labelCol">Opportunity Name</td>
            <td class="data2Col"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Opportunityid}"/></td>
        </tr>
       <!-- <tr>
            <td class="labelCol">Product</td>
            <td class="data2Col"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.QuoteLineItems__c.Product2}"/></td>
        </tr>-->
    </table>
    <!--<p>This document was created {!Now}.</p>-->

   <b>QuotelineItems</b>
    <table >

            <tr border="0">
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0" >PartNumbers</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0" >Price</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Quantity</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0" >EndcustomerPrice</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">TotalPrice</td>
            </tr>

        <tbody>
            <apex:repeat value="{!Quote.QuotelineItems}" var="qli">
            <tr border="0">
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!qli.Product2}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!qli.Unitprice}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputField value="{!qli.Quantity}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputField value="{!qli.Description}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputField value="{!qli.TotalPrice}"/></td>
            </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
        </tbody>
    </table> 


  <b>Justification and Account</b>
    <table >

            <tr border="0">
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">RFQ Justification</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0" >RecordType</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">no_of_opportunities</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0" >Description</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">pi_score</td>
            </tr>

        <tbody>
            <apex:repeat value="{!Quote.Account}" var="a">
            <tr border="0">
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!a.name}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!a.RecordType}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputField value="{!a.no_of_opportunities__c}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputField value="{!a.Description}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputField value="{!a.pi_score__c}"/></td>
            </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
        </tbody>
    </table> 



    <!-- Wrapper Class -->
   <!-- <h1>Student</h1>
    <table class="bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="header-table-heading">Studentname</th>
                <th class="header-table-heading">StudentDOB</th>
                <th class="header-table-heading">StudentSkills</th>
                <th class="header-table-heading">StudentLocation</th>
                <th class="header-table-heading">StudentResult</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <apex:repeat value="{!Student}" var="std">
            <tr>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!std.name}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!std.StudentDOB__c}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputField value="{!std.StudentSkills__c}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputField value="{!std.StudentLocation__c}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputField value="{!std.StudentResult__c}"/></td>
            </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
        </tbody>
    </table> -->



</apex:page>
```

Apex Class :

```
public with sharing class QuoteContentController {

    public QuoteContentController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }

//public  QuoteContentcontroller()
//public  QuoteLineItem(get;set;)
// Creating lists for the object Quote ,Quotelineitems ,Account and opportunity & opportunity forecast(wrapper class).
/*list<Quote> q = new list<Quote>();
list<QuoteLineItem> quoteLineItems = new list<QuoteLineItem>();
list<Account> account = new list<Account>();
list<Opportunity>opportunity = new list<Opportunity>();*/

// Creating List for Wrapper class

//public List<wrapper> Student = new List<wrapper>();

// Get method calling from PageBlockTable and return the list of wrapper to Table

public List<wrapper> getStudent() {

  q = [select id , name ,BillingName from Quote];
 quoteLineItems = [select id, UnitPrice ,Quantity ,Description ,TotalPrice from QuotelineItem ];
 account =[select id , name ,  description from Account];
 opportunity =[select id , name from Opportunity];

 for(Integer i=0;i<q.size();i++){
Student.add(new wrapper(q[i].name,q[i].id,q[i].BillingName,
                        quoteLineItems[i].id,quoteLineItems[i].Product2,quoteLineItems[i].UnitPrice,quoteLineItems[i].Quantity,quoteLineItems[i].Description,quoteLineItems[i].TotalPrice,
                        account[i].id,account[i].name,account[i].recordtype,account[i].Description,
                        opportunity[i].id,opportunity[i].name));

}

return Student;*/

// Wrapper Class Construction

public class wrapper{

public String Qname{get;set;}

public String QBillingName{get;set;}

public String QLIProduct2{get;set;}

public String QLIUnitprice{get;set;}

public String QLIQuantity{get;set;}

public String QLIDescription{get;set;}

public String QLITotalprice{get;set;}

public String AName{get;set;}

public String Arecordtype{get;set;}

public String ADescription{get;set;}

public String OppName{get;set;}
// Wrapper class constructor

public wrapper(String Qname,String QBillingName,String QLIProduct2,String QLIUnitprice,String QLIQuantity,String QLIDescription,String QLITotalprice,String AName,String Arecordtype,String ADescription,String OppName){

this.Qname=Qname;

this.QBillingName=QBillingName;

this.QLIProduct2=QLIProduct2;

this.QLIUnitprice=QLIUnitprice;

this.QLIQuantity=QLIQuantity;

this.QLIDescription=QLIDescription;

this.QLITotalprice=QLITotalprice;

this.AName=AName;

this.Arecordtype=Arecordtype;

this.ADescription=ADescription;

this.OppName=OppName
}

}
```

Comment: Wow!!! I need few days to read this. :-O

Comment: @nikkey - You may want to break this up into smaller questions...